How to ClearAll["Global`*"] when I close any notebook?
Assume there are several notebooks opened. I want to ClearAll["Global`*"] when I close any notebook(by clicking the close button of the window).
The code below is my attempt although it does not work the way I prefer. Only when the notebook with the code ran is closed would all the variables reset.
SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], NotebookEventActions -> {"WindowClose" :> ClearAll["Global`*"]}]

How shall I modify the code so that the ClearAll applies when whichever notebook is closed?

Why do you need to clear global variables for? since you are closing the notebook any way? Can you give a use case where this will make difference?

Perhaps several notebook windows are open, and OP wants to close just one of them.

All opened notebooks have global variables, while I want to reset all the global varibles after running any notebook(the notebook may have errors). @Nasser

Perhaps is better to keep the Kernel clean, see here

If you set each notebook not to share its variables with other notebooks variables (which is the right way to do work), see is-there-a-way-to-separate-variables-between-multiple-notebooks then when you close one notebooks, its own global variables are gone automatically.   So I still do not see what the issue is.  Think of each notebook as its own container with its own global variables no one else sees.

Another option if the above does not work you, is to have each notebook use its own kernel.

Look at: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RunOnQuit
